# How to find a specific html color code?

Tags: html, css

I have buttons with a color for each state :
state enable : #007BC2
state disable : #428bca  (pale version of enable color)

This css is a file I have picked from a template.

Now my client wants for the button this enable color : #4B0082.
I want to find the color code for the pale version of #4B0082 (for the disable state). 
Is there a css tool on the web to find this color or do I need to browse a color picker to find the "pale" version of this enable color?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using chrome or firefox. Here you can right-click any element on your webpage. For your example: right click the button and click 'inspect element'. You can now see the developer tools window. Here you can see all the css or html attributes for your button.

So take a look at the background-color attribute and click the color thumbnail. A color picker becomes visible (see screenshot) . You can now choose the color and see a live preview of that color in your web page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Colorzilla (chrome add-on) to pick color from page and to find its pale version.It also contain option of generating css gradient and even get history of your picked color
You will find colorzilla on chrome webstore

Comment: I have this tool. I can pick a color from a page, do you mean I need then to browse the color picker to find the pale version or does colorzilla provides this color version?